# How to access query parameters with dots in ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express

Imagine I have the following incoming request with query parameters

https://api.myawesomeapi.com/v1/facebook/group_app_install_hook?hub.mode=subscribe&hub.challenge=1409653872&hub.verify_token=myToken

then I have my express function as below to handle the incoming request above

```
static async appInstallOnGroupHookHandler(req, res) {
  let hubChallenge = req.query["hub.challenge"]; // This is always undefined
  console.log(`Hub Challenge ${hubChallenge}`);

  let verificationToken = req.query["hub.verify_token"];
  console.log(`Hub Verification Token=${verificationToken}`);

  return res.status(200).send(hubChallenge ?? 'success');
}
```

When I tried accessing the `hub.challenge` query parameter using

```
let hubChallenge = req.query["hub.challenge"];
```

`hubChallenge` keeps coming back as `undefined`.

Is there a better way to access query parameters that has the *dot* character in them?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried escaping the period with a backslash? ex. `req.query["hub\.challenge"]` Otherwise print the entirety of `req.query` to see how it's being stored: `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.query))`

Comment: What version of express are you using?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I use `express-mongo-sanitize` middleware that removes the "." and "$" from the request, and therefor also `req.query["hub\.challenge"]` - to fix my problem I just added the flag `allowDots` to the middleware -

```js
app.use(mongoSanitize({ allowDots: true }));
```